# Java overload confusion

Tags: java, overloading

java is not able to call any overload method as shown below :-

```
class LspTest{

    public void add(int a, float b){
    System.out.println("First add");
}

public void add(float a, int b){
    System.out.println("second add");
}

public static void main(String [] a){
    LspTest test = new LspTest();
    test.add(1,1);
   }
}
```

Please explain i am confused in this.

Comment: As you are new user here, let me tell you, you should accept an answer here if you get the solution of your problem. You can accept one answer per question and to do so you can click on the Right tick sign on the left side of answer which you want to accept. It helps others to know what worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

In your methods you are having parameters `(int, float)` and `(float, int)` but when calling the method you are passing both the `int` `(1,1)` values. The Java complier can auto type cast float to int whenever needed. But in this case compiler cannot decide auto type cast which int to float. Therefore it shows ambiguity.

You need to call it `test.add(1f, 1);` or `test.add(1,1f);` i.e. specify which value is int and which value is float.

P.S. To specify a value to be float you can write `f` with it.

Comment: Not really. 1 can be `float` or `int` because `float b = 1` will compile just fine. The issue is with these specific literals, the exact type cannot be inferred.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Yes. And to define that exact type I have written `f` with them.

Comment: That is correct. My point is that it is incorrect to say that (1,1) are both treated as int. If that were the case, the error would be no matching overload found, instead of ambiguous reference. Take a look at this test code: http://rextester.com/VPOUG32202

Comment: @shree.pat18 The two values mentioned are `int` no doubt. But I believe thing is compiler cannot decide auto type cast which int to float. As you say `float b = 1` will compile, in this an integer value is getting automatically type casted to float because it is similar to writing `int a = 1;` `float b = a;`

Answer (score 2):

When you initialise with literal values, in this case, compiler won't be able to infer the exact type. Therefore, it does not know which overload to call and returns the error that the reference to `add` is ambiguous. You can fix this by casting the arguments to the appropriate type, or even better, creating typed local variables initialised with 1 and passing the variables as parameters, like so:

```
int a = 1;
float b = 1;
LspTest test = new LspTest();
test.add(a,b);
```

Comment: `float b = 1` here `1` is an `integer` value which is getting automatically type casted to `float`. It is similar to writing `float b = (float) 1;`

Comment: True. I put in 1 simply because that was OP's original literal. By right the variable should be initialised as 1f.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ambiguity here, and the Java compiler cannot figure out which method to call. Use `test.add((float) 1, 1)` or `test.add(1, (float) 1)` to explicitly tell which method you want.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the clear case of ambiguity which leads to a Compile Error.

Java compiler supports the type promotion. First of all, it'll checks for more specific data type if not match then it'll promote to next data type.

Java compiler will supports the type promotion in following order.

> byte --> short --> int --> long --> float --> double

As your parameters (int,int) can be auto-promoted to float, java compiler can't decide in which one to invoke as both of your methods accepts the (1,1)